# Values with table in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello guys I was little bit confused by seeing a code. The code is

```
DECLARE @missingStates varChar(30)
SET @missingStates = Select StateCode FROM StateTable
WHERE GETDATE() NOT Between StateTable.EffectiveDate AND StateTable.ExpirationDate
PRINT 'States Missing Effective Models'
PRINT @missingStates
```

I just need to know the purpose of `EffectiveDate` and `ExpirationDate` in the above query.

I just need to know `EffectiveDate` and `ExpirationDate` here. Is this the column in `statetable`?  Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: yes, it is. (assuming that code works.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that query, it looks like in StateTable there is a StateCode defined for a period of time. for example,

```
Effective Date     Expiration Date     StateCode
12-01-2013         12-31-2013          SC1312
01-01-2014         01-31-2014          SC1401
```

Now, the query is trying to find out if for a given date (today = getdate()) if there is no date range (given date not falling between effectivedate & expirationdate), get the statecode.

From my understanding above,

1. if the data is like what I assumed above, then the query will fail if there is no "TOP 1" for that statement
2. if the data is not what I assumed above, then the query will work.